Adjust the beamer body block width with hbox in tcolorbox theme
I found a nice solution to get the text width here and for adjust the title width but in this case I would like see the same behaviour for body block width instead title.
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
    hbox,
    borderline={1pt}{0pt}{black,dashed}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Title}
            Text with body width.
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}



The tcolorbox inner theme does mainly two things: making sure that the tcolorbox used for the block is the same size as the ordinary beamer blocks and changing the colours to match the ordinary beamer blocks. If you don't need the boxes to be the same size as ordinary beamer blocks, I'd directly use \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title,hbox]      test with body width      \end{tcolorbox} instead of a block (colours can be adjusted in case you use a theme)

Thanks, the solution it works
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
    borderline={1pt}{0pt}{black,dashed}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Invariance,hbox]
            Text with body width.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}


